# Creating a simple Hello World tool that runs as a daemon

Tags: macos, cocoa, launchd

I built the Command Line tool (Foundation) template in Xcode. It just logs "Hello World" to the console.There is only one class in it main.m. Here's the code:

> ```
> #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
>
> int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
> ```
>
> {
>
> ```
>    @autoreleasepool {
>
>        // insert code here...
>        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
>
>    }
>    return 0;
> ```
>
> }

Now I want to run it as a daemon and log "Hello World" to the console every 10 seconds. So I moved the product/binary to */tmp* on my Mac. I created the following plist for launchd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>helloDaemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/tmp/helloDaemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I loaded the plist using launchctl, but I do not see any "Hello World"s in the console. Instead, I get this:

```
11/03/2012 00:55:35.141 com.apple.launchd: (helloDaemon) Throttling respawn: Will start in 1 seconds
11/03/2012 00:55:45.141 com.apple.launchd: (helloDaemon) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2 seconds
11/03/2012 00:55:55.140 com.apple.launchd: (helloDaemon) Throttling respawn: Will start in 3 seconds
```

So what's going wrong?

Comment: Where did you install the launchd plist?

Comment: @RobKeniger I used `launchctl` to install the plist. Also as I loaded it as the root user (using sudo) it should had been installed in /Library/LaunchDaemons. But well, my plist was not copied in that directory (I think only the daemons which start at reboot are placed there). So I manually copied it over to /Library/LaunchDaemons, but still no luck.

Comment: @RobKeniger But I think it was loaded correctly by launchctl. When I type `sudo launchctl list`, it lists my daemon with status 0.

Comment: Ok, apparently my daemon is working. Instead of logging to console, I directed the output to a file, and it worked. So for some reason, `NSLog`s don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSLog is not working because when you launch a demon process it does not have any standard io sockets or file handles attached to it.  They have to be specifically allocated.  A good resource for how to create a proper daemon and how to write the console and syslog is provided in the book "Advanced Mac OS X Programming (chapter 20) by Dalrymple & Hillegass.

They have define a skeleton program that addresses the io issues you highlight. I remembered reading it a while ago and thought that maybe someday I'd need it.  The authors show a sample using the syslog.h lib using openlog() and syslog() for simple communications.  They also show some other lower level methods for communication to files and even sockets (for servers, etc).

I always appreciate when someone can tell me how to do something rather than reference something, but in this case, that is the best I can do.  good luck.

Comment: I NSLog all the time in my OS X daemons. You find the output in the system log.

Answer (score 3):

Just add to your launchd plist

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/yourpath/sample.log</string>
```

You can `tail -f` it afterwards.

More info is here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION39

Answer (score 2):

With the following keys in the `plist` file I get most of the logs. But sometimes I am confused if I get all the `NSLog` output in the log file. To me it seems sometime some logs line are missing.

I am not sure if all the `NSLog` output of a `LaunchDaemon` is logged or some are skipped due to system priority.

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/mydaemon.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/mydaemon.log</string>
```